# How to read a text file line by line subsequently followed by button click

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a text file that is stored in my local disk.Now in my winform application i have a button.As per my requirement i have to read that text file line by line upon the click of the Button.For example ,On first button click it should read first line of the textfile and on second button click it should read second line and so on.
I know how to read a textfile line by line in c# but on every button click i am having problem.

Here is the code to read line by line ..

```
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader("C://");
string line=sr.ReadLine();
```

Please help me ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason it needs to be READ line by line? Could you not read the entire file into a list or array when your form is loaded then just iterate through a list of lines? You would just need to keep track of the current button click count and use that to get the line from a list / array.

```
public class TextReader : Form
{
    string[] lines;
    int currentIndex = 0;
    public TextReader ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\myTextFile.txt"); 
    }

    public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = lines[currentIndex];
        currentIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added example, might need tidying up! Also there is no checking to see if you are at the end of the file, so you might want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to keep the `StreamReader` open for the duration of your form's life.

```
public class mainForm : Form
{
    public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        m_lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(path).GetEnumerator();
        // alternatively, m_lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path).GetEnumerator();
        // this would read it all at once, which would have the advantage of not locking up the file, but would take longer to load and would be harder on memory.
    }

    private IEnumerator<string> m_lines;

    public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_lines.MoveNext())
            TextBox1.Text = m_lines.Current;
        else
            MessageBox.Show("End of file!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `m_Reader = null;` a read only can not be defined here error..Also `protected override Dispose(bool disposing)` method is asking to return value.And what to enter here `"[End of File]"`

Comment: @user3816352 Sorry, typos. This is what I get for not compiling first. It should be better now. You can decide what you want the textbox to do when the end of the file is hit. But in this particular example, I chose to make it say "[End of File]."